# Move data from Screens - Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, screen

I dont know why, it dosent work.
I want to move data from Screen2 to Screen1 from TextField
Theres no erros, and app works good on phone, but dosent show data.\

Main
https://github.com/fornakter/Navigation-With-Data/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/nav/controllerwithdata/MainActivity.kt

Screen1
https://github.com/fornakter/Navigation-With-Data/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/nav/controllerwithdata/screens/Screen1.kt

Screen2
https://github.com/fornakter/Navigation-With-Data/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/nav/controllerwithdata/screens/Screen2.kt

Comment: Post the relevant bits, I dont see in Screen1 where you retrieve the data. In screen 2 set data on currentBackStab then nagivate, on Screen2 pull it from the previousbackStabEntry

Comment: What can i say... thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

In screen 2 set the data on `currentBackStabEntry` then nagivate, on Screen2 pull it from the `previousbackStabEntry`